# Where does Dialogflow store simple responses?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

For example: I add a simple response to an intent with Dialogflow interface,
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/futDe.png).

This response is associated with my intent and my agent, but where is it stored? Is there some google db? Can I access all the agent data stored by dialogflow?
I can't find any hints in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**Where is it stored? Is there some google db?**

There is a data store of some sort, just like most things are stored in a database or data store of some sort. But that doesn't mean that it is a conventional database in the way you may think about it.

It also doesn't mean that you would have access to the database directly.

**Can I access all the agent data stored by dialogflow?**

Depends what you mean by "all the agent data". Everything that you build using the web interface (the Intents and Entities, for example) is available to you. You can  [export it as a zip file](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-settings#export) that contains various JSON files with the configuration. You can also use the [Dialogflow API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2-overview) to get various parts of your configuration.